# Separation of a SQLite database

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3

I work on a project that uses a SQLite database in Swift 4, Swift 5, I have a code that works when it is located in the "viewController" from which you want to access the database, but when I integrate it into a class individual to avoid redundant code gives me the message "SQL logic error" I understand the meaning of the message and the reason that produces the problem is that the code is tested and the sentences are correct, only fails to separate it and call it from another class in the "viewController"
Attached a link to full project for stakeholders: https://github.com/dqueralto/TFG

I have tried "DispatchQueue ... background" and different types of functions (private, public, internal), I can not think of anything else because I am new to Swift

```
import UIKit
import SQLite3

class ViewController: UIViewController{
private var db: OpaquePointer?
private var dbName: String = "Datos.sqlite"
private var usuarios = [Usuario]()
private var conexion = ConexionDB()


@IBOutlet weak var usuario: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var contrasenia: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var alerta: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var alerta2: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {//hilo de fonde
        print("Esto se ejecuta en la cola de fondo")
        self.conexion.conectarDB()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {//hilo principal
            print("Esto se ejecuta en la cola principal, después del código anterior en el bloque externo")

            //Creación de ADMIN en caso de no existir al menos un usuario----------------------------------------------
            if self.usuarios.count == 0
            {
                self.conexion.insertarUsuario(usu: "admin", pass: "admin", tipo: "A",nom: "Administrador",apell: "Administrador",fec_nac: "16/10/1996",email: "admin@admin.admin",sexo: "poco")
                self.conexion.insertarUsuario(usu: "vu", pass: "vu", tipo: "U",nom: "Vista Usario",apell: "Vista Usario",fec_nac: "16/10/1996",email: "vu@vu.vu",sexo: "poco")
                if self.usuarios.count == 2
                {
                    print("ADMIN insertado al loguear")
                }else if self.usuarios.count == 0
                {
                    print("ADMIN no se ha podido insertar al loguearse")
                }
            }

            for usu in self.usuarios
            {
                print("usu: "+usu.usuario)
                print("pass: "+usu.contrasenia)
                print("tipo: "+usu.tipo)
            }
            print("fin :"+String(self.usuarios.count))

        }//fin hilo de principal
    }//fin del hilo de fondo

}
```

---

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3

internal class ConexionDB {

var db: OpaquePointer?
var usuarios = [Usuario]()
private var dbName: String = "Datos.sqlite"


internal func conectarDB()
{
    //INDICAMOS DONDE SE GUARDARA LA BASE DE DATOS Y EL NOMBRE DE ESTAS
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("Datos.sqlite")
    //INDICAMOS SI DIERA ALGUN FALLO AL CONECTARSE
    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error al abrir la base de datos")
    }
    else {//SI PODEMOS CONECTARNOS A LA BASE DE DATOS CREAREMOS LA ESTRUCTURA DE ESTA, SI NO EXISTIERA NO SE HARIA NADA
        print("base abierta")
        //if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (usuario TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contrasenia TEXT, tipo TEXT, nombre TEXT)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (usuario TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contrasenia TEXT, tipo TEXT, nombre TEXT, apellidos TEXT, fec_nac TEXT, email TEXT,sexo TEXT);COMMIT;", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            //if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (usuario TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contrasenia TEXT, tipo TEXT, nombre TEXT, apellidos TEXT, fec_nac TEXT, email TEXT,sexo TEXT); CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movimientos (num_reg TEXT PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY(usuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario), fecha TEXT, importe REAL, tipo BOOLEAN);", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
        }
    }
    print("BD creada")
    self.crearObjUsuario()
    print("Usuarios creados")
    if usuarios.count == 0
    {
        self.insertarUsuario(usu: "admin", pass: "admin", tipo: "A",nom: "Administrador",apell: "Administrador",fec_nac: "16/10/1996",email: "admin@admin.admin",sexo: "poco")
        print("ADMIN insertado.")
    }

}

internal func conectarDB(nombreDB: String)
{
    //INDICAMOS DONDE SE GUARDARA LA BASE DE DATOS Y EL NOMBRE DE ESTAS
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent(nombreDB)
    //INDICAMOS SI DIERA ALGUN FALLO AL CONECTARSE
    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error al abrir la base de datos")
    }
    else {//SI PODEMOS CONECTARNOS A LA BASE DE DATOS CREAREMOS LA ESTRUCTURA DE ESTA, SI NO EXISTIERA NO SE HARIA NADA
        print("base abierta")
        //if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (usuario TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contrasenia TEXT, tipo TEXT, nombre TEXT)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (usuario TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contrasenia TEXT, tipo TEXT, nombre TEXT, apellidos TEXT, fec_nac TEXT, email TEXT,sexo TEXT);COMMIT;", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            //if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuarios (usuario TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contrasenia TEXT, tipo TEXT, nombre TEXT, apellidos TEXT, fec_nac TEXT, email TEXT,sexo TEXT); CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movimientos (num_reg TEXT PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY(usuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario), fecha TEXT, importe REAL, tipo BOOLEAN);", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
        }
    }
    print("BD creada")
    self.crearObjUsuario()
    print("Usuarios creados")
    if usuarios.count == 0
    {
        self.insertarUsuario(usu: "admin", pass: "admin", tipo: "A",nom: "Administrador",apell: "Administrador",fec_nac: "16/10/1996",email: "admin@admin.admin",sexo: "poco")
        print("ADMIN insertado.")
    }

}



internal func crearObjUsuario(){


    //GUARDAMOS NUESTRA CONSULTA
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios;"

    //PUNTERO DE INSTRUCCIÓN
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //PREPARACIÓN DE LA CONSULTA
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //RECORREMOS LOS REGISTROS
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        print("illo")
        let usuario = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))
        let contrasenia = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let tipo = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
        let nombre = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
        let apellidos = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4))
        let fec_nac = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5))
        let email = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6))
        let sexo = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 7))
        print("illo2")
        //AÑADIMOS LOS VALORES A LA LISTA
        self.usuarios.append(Usuario(
            usuario: String(describing: usuario),
            contrasenia: String(describing: contrasenia),
            tipo:String(describing: tipo)
            ,nombre:String(describing: nombre)
            ,apellidos:String(describing: apellidos)
            ,fec_nac:String(describing: fec_nac)
            ,email:String(describing: email)
            ,sexo:String(describing: sexo)

        ))
    }
    print("siiiiiiiiii")
}

internal func insertarUsuario(usu:String,pass:String, tipo: String, nom: String,apell: String, fec_nac: String,email: String, sexo: String)  {
    //CREAMOS EL PUNTERO DE INSTRUCCIÓN
    var stmt: OpaquePointer?

    //CREAMOS NUESTRA SENTENCIA
    let queryString = "INSERT INTO Usuarios(usuario, contrasenia, tipo, nombre, apellidos, fec_nac, email, sexo) VALUES ('"+usu+"','"+pass+"','"+tipo+"','"+nom+"','"+apell+"','"+fec_nac+"','"+email+"','"+sexo+"');commit;"
    //PREPARAMOS LA SENTENCIA
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print(queryString)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }


    //EJECUTAMOS LA SENTENCIA PARA INSERTAR LOS VALORES
    if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("fallo al insertar en usuarios: \(errmsg)")
        //nurvc.alerta2.isHidden = true
        //nurvc.alerta3.isHidden = true
        //nurvc.alerta.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    //FINALIZAMOS LA SENTENCIA
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
    print("Insertado")
    //displaying a success message
    print("Usuario saved successfully")

}

internal func eliminarUsuarios()
{
    //GUARDAMOS NUESTRA CONSULTA
    let queryString = "DELETE FROM Usuarios;COMMIT;"
    //CREAMOS EL PUNTERO DE INSTRUCCIÓN
    var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    //PREPARACIÓN DE LA CONSULTA
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print(queryString)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }
    //ELIMINAMOS LOS REGISTROS
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(deleteStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully deleted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not delete row.")
        }
    } else {
        print("DELETE statement could not be prepared")
    }

    //FINALIZAMOS LA SENTENCIA
    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
    //insertarAdmin()
}

internal func eliminarUsuario(usu: String)
{
    //GUARDAMOS NUESTRA CONSULTA
    let queryString = "DELETE FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario ='"+usu+"';COMMIT;"
    //CREAMOS EL PUNTERO DE INSTRUCCIÓN
    var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    //PREPARACIÓN DE LA CONSULTA
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print(queryString)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }
    //ELIMINAMOS LOS REGISTROS
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(deleteStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully deleted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not delete row.")
        }
    } else {
        print("DELETE statement could not be prepared")
    }

    //FINALIZAMOS LA SENTENCIA
    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
    //insertarAdmin()
}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking and why you get the error, please try to clarify the question and where in your code you get the error. You say "... the reason that produces the problem is that the code is tested and the sentences are correct", did you forget a "not" there or? I think you need to go through this part and correct it.

Comment: In English, every sentence must end with the period, not the comma.  The same is true for Spanish.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax. The bug is given by separating the database-related code from the "viewController". The code I use to communicate with the database is tested and working. But I can't make it work in a separate class.

Comment: why do u call self.conexion.insertarUsuario on main thread ? You should call in background thread.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. But I think I'm calling "self. conexion. conectarDB ()" in the background thread. (I'M new to Swift and it's my first time working with threads)